# How to send emails with both text part and html table in python?

Tags: python, html

I am using below method to send emails with a text part and a html table. For the html table, i have used pretty_html_table library.

First I got table data using a query as below.

```
def get_data():
    """"
    data
    :return:
    """
    df = pd.read_sql(raw_data_query, db_connection)
    data=pd.DataFrame(df)
  
    return data
```

Then I have initated a sendmail method as below.

```
    def send_mail(body):
        message=MIMEMultipart()
        message['From']=''
        message['To']='>'
        message['Subject']="Daily Termination Data  "
        
        text = f"""


Dear All,<br/><br/> Please refer below termination data :<br/><br/>

<b>This is an automated email, Please do not reply ...</b>
"""
    
    body_content=body
    message.attach(MIMEText(text,"html"))
    message.attach(MIMEText(body_content,"html"))
    msg_body=message.as_string()
    
    
    try:
      smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('XXX',25)
      smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg_body)         
      print ("Successfully sent email")
        
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
      print ("Error: unable to send email")
      smtpObj.quit()
```

Then finally I add the output as below.

```
data =get_data()
data
output=build_table(data,"blue_light")
send_mail(output)
```

This works fine and I am getting emails.But the issue is the text part is in a body and the html table in a attachment.

[image]

Can someone show where I have messed up?

Edit:

```
data =get_data()
data

    Name    Terminated_Date Calls   Answered_Calls  Total_Minutes
0   XXX       2021-12-21    522273  124018  408328.17
1   XXX       2021-12-20    508439  124895  407590.03
2   XXX       2021-12-19    456587  107899  384698.82
```

Comment: Can you show me the output of get_data?

Comment: updated in the question

Comment: To do what you're asking, your main email must be of type `multipart/alternative`, to which you add a `text/plain` subpart and a `text/html` subpart.  You do understand that users will see either one or the other, but not both?

Comment: No I need to show both text part as well as the html table part. I have used "alternative" in side the message=MIMEMultipart(), but it only shows one of them not both. I need to show both.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use Python format and MIMEMultipart.

Basically, you can do

```
message = MIMEMultipart()

html = """\
        <html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <p>The text you want </p>
            <br>
            {0}
          </body>
        </html>
        """.format(df_test.to_html())

 message.attach(MIMEText(html, "HTML"))
```

Hope this is helpful. I am working on the same thing. Takes me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Use html Paragraph element for text part, rest html part will be the same.

also remove mentioned function from your code.
`message.attach(MIMEText(text,"html"))`